# Custom Delegate Method Not Being Called in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

A user is prompted to login in `ViewController`. When the user clicks the login button, `LoginService`'s method `loginWithUsername:andWithPassword` is called. This method uses `NSURLConnection` to fetch data from a web service and it authenticates the login credentials. It is an `NSURLConnection` delegate (now I know there is another NSURLConnection method that uses block, I just prefer this one because I understand this, at least haha).

I have set a protocol called `LoginServiceProtocol`, with a delegate method called `loginResult` which accepts an NSDictionary parameter `loginData`.

When the `NSURLConnection` delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called, I want to call the method `loginResult` and set its `loginData` parameter to the data fetched from the website.

My problem is, I can't seem to be able to call the `loginResult` method.

To set the protocol, I have this code for LoginService.h:

```
//To create a protocol
@protocol LoginServiceProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)loginResult:(NSDictionary*)loginData;

@end
//End of protocol creation

@interface LoginService : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{
    NSMutableData* _responseData; //Response data catches the data received from the web api
    id<LoginServiceProtocol>delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <LoginServiceProtocol> delegate;
```

This is my LoginService.m implementation in the connectionDidFinishLoading NSURLConnection delegate method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSDictionary *loginDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:nil];
[self loginResult:loginDict];
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loginResult:)]){
    [self.delegate loginResult:loginDict];
}
}
```

I wrote `[self loginResult:loginDict]` because without it, even the implementation of the delegate method in `LoginService.m` isn't called. Without it, the program does nothing. It does not show or do anything, even in my `ViewController` which is a delegate of `LoginService`. The implementation of `loginResult` in my `LoginService.m` is just an `NSLog()` checking if the method ever gets called.

I know I'm missing a very vital thing, but I can't find it out. I've been trying for quite a while now. Also, I get this warning:

```
Authosynthesized property 'delegate' will use synthesised instance variable '_delegate', not existing instance variable 'delegate'.
```

I used the delegate in ViewController. Here is my ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginService.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<LoginServiceProtocol>{

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblName;

- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnKeyResign:(id)sender;
- (void)loginResult:(NSDictionary *)loginData;

@end
```

And I used it in the ViewController.m like this, just to see if it gets called:

```
- (void)loginResult:(NSDictionary *)loginData{
    NSLog(@"Reached");
}
```

I assigned it in the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    LoginService* login = [[LoginService alloc]init];
    login.delegate = self;

}
```

Most recent LoginService.h

```
//Declaring custom delegate
@protocol LoginServiceProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)loginResult:(NSDictionary*)loginData;

@end


@interface LoginService : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{
    NSMutableData* _responseData;
    id<LoginServiceProtocol>_delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)id<LoginServiceProtocol>delegate;
//End of custom delegate declaration
```

Most recent viewDidLoad implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.ls.delegate=self; //Where ls is a strong reference of LoginService declared in .h

}
```

Comment: Where does that warning show up?

Comment: @nhgrif in the `@implementation LoginService` in LoginService.m file

Comment: In your implementation file include @synthesize delegate

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
id<LoginServiceProtocol>delegate;
```

from here:

```
@interface LoginService : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{
    NSMutableData* _responseData; //Response data catches the data received from the web api
    id<LoginServiceProtocol>delegate;
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the warning, but still, the delegate method in LoginService.m does not get called :( I mean, without [self loginResult]. Even in the `ViewController`, `loginResult` method is not called.

Comment: Are you implementing loginResult in the delegate?

Comment: Yes. But I only have NSLog at the moment to see if the method gets called, and it's not…..

Comment: Can I see where you asign the delegate?

Comment: And how do you asign it?

Comment: Try removing this - (void)loginResult:(NSDictionary *)loginData; from the viewcontroller.h

Comment: Still doesn't get called :(

Answer (score 0):

Your controller creates an instance of `LoginService` but doesn't take ownership of it, so the instance is deallocated at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Add a `strong` property to your view controller class and store the reference to the `LoginService` instance there rather than in a local variable. (Note that even if you had done that in the first place, your implementation would still have been broken due to the bug that @AntonioMG pointed out).

Comment: I already did that. But I think I just found out my problem. Delegate is nil. I hope you, sir, can help me fix it. I will update the question with my most recent protocol declaration.